# Code is not opening OneNote Online in New Window

Tags: sharepoint-online, jquery, onenote

I have this code to open files in a new window. When I open one note. Instead of opening the OneNote online, it opens a page with all the OneNote sections listed as individual one notes. Why is this?

```
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.7.2.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>

<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(
        function () {
            // has to be on an interval for grouped doc libraries
            // where the actual links are loaded only once a group
            // is expanded
            setInterval(
                function () {
                    $("a[onclick*=’return DispEx’][target!=’_blank’]")
                        .attr("target", "_blank")
                        .removeAttr("onclick");

                    // document type icons
                    $("td.ms-vb-icon>img[onclick]:not([documentUrl])")
                        .click(function (e) {
                            window.open($(this).attr("documentUrl"), "_blank");
                            e.stopPropagation();
                            e.preventDefault();
                            return false;
                        })
                        .each(function () {
                            $(this).attr(
                                "documentUrl",
                                $.trim(String($(this).attr("onclick"))
                                    .split("=")[1]
                                    .replace(/["'{}]/g, "")
                                    .split(";")[0])
                                );
                            this.onclick = null;
                        });
                    },
                    500
            );
        }
    );
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

Remove the js code and check if it works.

By default, open OneNote file like this:

[image]

You can provide the screenshots for further research.